# configure: error: Could not determine kernel version

Tags: configure

I want to compile **ocfs2**, but, when i configure the compile environment, i meet those problems, can anyone help?

```
root@ubuntu:/home/dingjia/ocfs2-1.4.10# ./configure 
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for vendor... not found
checking for vendor kernel... not supported
checking for debugging... no
checking for directory with kernel build tree... not found
checking for kernel version... none
configure: error: Could not determine kernel version.
```